# Is 80 a strict Lighthouse scores for publishing TWA apps?

Tags: lighthouse, trusted-web-activity

While learning about TWAs, most of the google tutorials have given example of oyorooms.com for its OyoLite app in Playstore, Myntra.com ( Myntra lite ), NavbharathTimes

However, when I measured these sites on https://web.dev/measure/ or https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/, their respective scores were in the range of 20-40.

Google documentation talks about a score of 80+ for the PWA to be considered for playstore.
So, the question is whether this is a strict guidelines by Google?
My app's current score is 55, should I invest time to bring it to 80 or try publishing the app directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, publishing an app to the Play Store is not blocked on Lighthouse checks and applications are not suspended due to Lighthouse scores.

It is, however, strongly recommended and it will help ensure the application gets good reviews from users and that it has a quality similar to apps on the store built with other technologies.